# Search internal content fields

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcore

How can I set up a search on the Manage Content page so that I can search not only by headings but also by internal fields? for example htmlbody

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWvOq.png)

Answer (score 0):

When the search feature is enabled, each content type has a setting to define exactly what is part of the search index. What you are asking for should be the default.

[image]

What might be your issue is that your content type is not selected in the index you created.

If you want to add more fields, then in the "Full-Text" section of the content type definition, check "Use custom full-text".

Comment: If I turn on "use custom full-text", and indicate for example stereotypes "Model.Content.HtmlBodyPart" then in the administrative panel, on the page "/ Admin / Contents /" can I search not only by title but also by HtmlBodyPart?

Comment: and which modules should be included and configured for my task?

Comment: and indicate for example tempate "Model.Content.HtmlBodyPart"

p.s. accidentally made a mistake in a previous message